# ¿Cómo usar condicional if, para cambiar un value en un array?

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, test

Tengo una función, la cual debería actualizar un valor de una propiedad, pero el test indica que es un `undefined` dicha actualización, en un array de objetos:

```
const accessories = [{
  id: 1,
  type: 'Sweater',
  color: 'White',
  description: 'White Sweater',
  popularity: 'low'
},
{
  id: 2,
  type: 'Bun',
  color: 'Purple',
  description: 'Purple Bun',
  popularity: 'low'
}]
```

Siguiendo ciertas instrucciones a continuación, agradezco por sus aportes para poder pasar el test.

"Actualiza la popularidad del accesorio dependiendo de cuantos gatos lo vistan".

```
// Actualiza la propiedad <popularity> del accesorio,
    // Para eso deberás comprobar cuantos gatos visten el accesorio recibido por parámetros (es un id)
    // Si la cantidad de gatos que visten el accesorio son 2, entonces la popularidad del accesorio debe valer 'average'
    // Si la cantidad de gatos que visten el accesorio son 3 (o mas), entonces la popularidad del accesorio debe valer 'high'
    // Si se actualizó la popularidad del accesorio, devolver un mensaje que diga 'La popularidad del accesorio <color_accesorio> <tipo_accesorio> fue actualizada a <popularidad>'
    // Si no se actualizó la popularidad del accesorio, devolver un mensaje que diga 'No hubieron cambios en la popularidad del accesorio <color_accesorio> <tipo_accesorio>'
    // Si el id de accesorio no existe arrojar un Error ('accesorio no encontrado' y no actualiza la popularidad)


updateAccessoryPopularity: function (accessoryId){
let accessory = accessories.find(acc => acc.id === accessoryId);
        if (!accessory) {
        throw new Error('accesorio no encontrado');
        }
        
        let numCatsUsingAccessory = cats.filter(cat => cat.accessories.includes(accessoryId)).length;
        let newPopularity;

        if(numCatsUsingAccessory.length){
          if (numCatsUsingAccessory.length === 2) {
            newPopularity = 'average';
        } else if (numCatsUsingAccessory.length >= 3) {
          newPopularity = 'high';
        } else {
          accessories.push(newPopularity)
          return `No hubieron cambios en la popularidad del accesorio ${accessory.color} ${accessory.type}`;
        }  
      }
  
  accessory.newPopularity = newPopularity; 
  return `La popularidad del accesorio ${accessory.color} 
  ${accessory.type} fue actualizada a ${accessory.newPopularity}`
}
```

Comment: En vez de `if (numCatsUsingAccessory.length)` pon `if (numCatsUsingAccessory)`

Comment: Considera aportar un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable que incluya el código de prueba así como un pequeño ejemplo de otros objetos que podrían estar implicados, en este caso, conviene ver cómo tienes organizado el objeto `cat`.